# python filtering meta characters while preserving the integrity of the words

Tags: python, regex, string

Hello I need to figure out how to count the number of words in a sentence but now I am stuck. The problem with my current code is that, it doesnt filter away meta characters, so string like "..." creates an error.

```
   print(len(input().split()))
```

another method i tried to use was this(which is to use regex to filer out the meta characters. but this only resulted in the len function counting all the characters not words present:

```
   import re

   print(len(re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]+',' ',input())))
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: my bad.., just added my tries. thanks!

Comment: added another example

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split` to split according to a separator (in your case default seperator of space character is enough) and then count the length of the list:

```
In [49]: my_str = 'A very valid, and nice example.'

In [50]: len(my_str.split())
Out[50]: 6
```

Edit: As you have punctuation characters in your example, you can first remove them:

```
In [59]: my_str
Out[59]: 'A very valid, and nice example.'

In [60]: len(re.sub('[^\w\s]', '', my_str).split())
Out[60]: 6

In [61]: len(re.sub('[^\w\s]', '', '...').split())
Out[61]: 0
```

So this will remove every character that is not alphanumeric and not space.

Comment: Thank you! It helps but unfortunately I am still getting the wrong answer and I have no idea why. Its an online question that I am trying so i can improve my skills but im in so much despair. I am suppose to "Input to your program will consist of a series of lines, each line containing multiple words (at least one).
A “word” is defined as a consecutive sequence of letters (upper and/or lower case)."

Comment: Try to come up with examples that fail and improve the regex I've provided so it works with those examples :)

Answer (score 0):

The below matches groups of letter characters. I tried before to utilize a couple different expressions, but symbol combinations such as '--' would get counted as words. Utilizing only the \w quantifier, this counts all groups of words and adds them to a list. Should you wish to see the words instead, remove the len quantifier. I tried this with as many examples as I could think of and it worked on all of them!

```
import re

def getWordCount(value):
    list = re.findall('([\w]+)',value)
    return len(list)

value = 'A very nice, and simple, example.'
print(getWordCount(value))
```

Comment: Please do not just put a code, explain why that answer the question